# Add an object of one class to an object of another class in python

Tags: python

I have a class Participant as follows:

```
class Participant: 

    def __init__(self,name,level):

        self.name = name
        self.level =level
```

I also have another class Team as follows:

```
class Team: 

    def __init__(self,name):

        self.name = name
```

I want to create a method in the class `Team` to add an instance of class `Participant`; for instance:

Assume `myTeam` is an empty, valid instance of Team. 
Also assume `myParticipant1` is a valid instances of Participant

```
myTeam.addParticipant(participant= myParticipant1)
```

`AddParticipant` method should add the instance `myParticipant1` to the instance `myTeam`.

How do I acheive it in Python?

Comment: Are you sure you want that inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: Am not sure, if it can be achieved without that, I can do that

Comment: An inheritance relationship implies that the child can be used wherever the parent can be used, so what you're asking along with that code means that you want to be able to have a team made out of teams.

Comment: Agreed that this seems like it's a place for composition (*"has a"*) not inheritance (*"is a"*). Teams HAVE participants, but Teams AREN'T participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the inheritance questions we're talking about in the comments, this is pretty simple stuff.

```
class Participant(object):
    def __init__(self, name, level):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level

class Team(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.participants = []

    def add_participant(self, p):
        self.participants.append(p)
```

DEMO:

```
my_team = Team("Monty Python")
p_info = [("Adam", 10e5), ("Joe-bob", -1)]
participants = [Participant(name, level) for name, level in p_info]

for participant in participants:
    my_team.add_participant(participant)
    # say that 10 times fast....

In [1]: [p.name for p in my_team.participants]
Out[1]: ["Adam", "Joe-bob"]
```

Comment: For extra credit, add an `__iter__` method that lets you iterate directly over the team. Or just derive `Team` from `list`.

Comment: @kindall right, but I'm not sure that `Team` IS a list, I just know that it HAS a list :)

Comment: Yeah, it could have other components such as resources or equipment that are also lists. :-)

Comment: I know it's an old post. But for me it doesnt work in Python3. I get "TypeError: add_participant() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". I copied the code 1-to-1. Seems like add_participiant takes only one argument, but we are adding two (name and level). How to fix that so it will be possible to add participiant name and level also?

Comment: @Learner looks like this answer has always been wrong. I fixed it!